# ¿Cómo cambiar el parámetro de un temporizador para ponerle un tiempo determinado?

Tags: javascript, date, setinterval

Tengo un temporizador el cual saqué del siguiente video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbF5qomB8XM el tema es que para este se le pone una fecha futura específica (deadline) y se resta esa fecha con la fecha actual (now), ahora bien lo que yo quiero es no que me haga la resta deadline-now sino que yo pueda ponerle un tiempo específico ejemplo 7 días el cual debe temporizar.Ya he intentado muchas variantes (ensayo error) pero ninguna me ha funcionado.

```js
const getRemainingTime = deadline => {
  let now = new Date(),
  remainTime = (new Date(deadline) - now + 1000)/ 1000,
  remainSeconds = ('0' + Math.floor(remainTime % 60)).slice(-2),
  remainMinutes = ('0' + Math.floor(remainTime / 60 % 60)).slice(-2),
  remainHours = ('0' + Math.floor(remainTime / 3600 % 24)).slice(-2),
  remainDays = Math.floor(remainTime / (3600 * 24));

  return {
    remainSeconds,
    remainMinutes,
    remainHours,
    remainDays,
    remainTime };

};

const countdown = (deadline, elem, finalMessage) => {
  const el = document.getElementById(elem);
 

  const timerUpdate = setInterval(()=> {
    let t = getRemainingTime(deadline);
    el.innerHTML = `${t.remainDays}d:${t.remainHours}h:${t.remainMinutes}m:${t.remainSeconds}s`;

    if (t.remainTime <= 1) {     
         clearInterval(timerUpdate);
         el.innerHTML = finalMessage;
         document.getElementById("av1").style.display="block";  
         document.getElementById("hr1").style.display="block";  
        }   

  }, 1000);
};

countdown('Jul 08 2019 15:26:40 GMT-0500' , 'clock', '¡Ya empezó!');
```

```html
    <div id="clock"></div>
    <script src="js/temporizador.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Disculpa, si entendí, ¿deseas que **let now = new Date()** sea parametrizable?

Comment: No termino de entender que querés lograr. Si elegís un día inicial a una fecha a futuro no hay countdown, sino solamente una diferencia de días, porque el countdown de por si no ha comenzado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es incluir una forma de obtener el plazo, luego podrías lograr lo que estas buscando calculando el primer argumento de la función `countdown`.

La parte de obtener el plazo puedes hacerlo con un prompt, un modal, etc. Para mostrar cómo calcular el plazo, voy a agregar la variable `sieteDias`

```
var sieteDias = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7);
console.info(new Date(sieteDias)); // Esta línea sólo es para observar la fecha límite que calculamos
countdown( sieteDias, 'clock', '¡Ya empezó!');
```

A continuación la demostración:

```js
const getRemainingTime = deadline => {
  let now = new Date(),
  remainTime = (new Date(deadline) - now + 1000)/ 1000,
  remainSeconds = ('0' + Math.floor(remainTime % 60)).slice(-2),
  remainMinutes = ('0' + Math.floor(remainTime / 60 % 60)).slice(-2),
  remainHours = ('0' + Math.floor(remainTime / 3600 % 24)).slice(-2),
  remainDays = Math.floor(remainTime / (3600 * 24));

  return {
    remainSeconds,
    remainMinutes,
    remainHours,
    remainDays,
    remainTime };

};

const countdown = (deadline, elem, finalMessage) => {
  const el = document.getElementById(elem);
 

  const timerUpdate = setInterval(()=> {
    let t = getRemainingTime(deadline);
    el.innerHTML = `${t.remainDays}d:${t.remainHours}h:${t.remainMinutes}m:${t.remainSeconds}s`;

    if (t.remainTime <= 1) {     
         clearInterval(timerUpdate);
         el.innerHTML = finalMessage;
         document.getElementById("av1").style.display="block";  
         document.getElementById("hr1").style.display="block";  
        }   

  }, 1000);
};
var sieteDias = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7);
console.info(new Date(sieteDias));
countdown( sieteDias, 'clock', '¡Ya empezó!');
```

```html
    <div id="clock"></div>
    <script src="js/temporizador.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias crack